# keycloak bearer token error - Didn't find publicKey for specified kid

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am following [this document](http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/10/getting-started-with-keycloak-securing.html) to secure the rest services. I am able to obtain the access token. However when I try to use the token to invoke a service, I am getting the error -

Status: 401

> WWW-Authenticate Bearer realm="bkofc", error="invalid_token",
>   error_description="Didn't find publicKey for specified kid"

What am I missing here ? Anything to do with the realm settings ?

Comment: Can you share the keycloak.json ? You might be missing the public key.

Answer (score 0):

401 could actually only mean, that the token is not provided correctly. The Header "Authorization" needs to be set properly. It actually works fine, when you are doint it right.

Desides, the document you are using is written by a person, who knows exactly, what to do for people, who know exaclty what to do. So may be you are just doing something wrong, which is not recognisable from your question.

Comment: Yes there was an inadvertent error on my part in the wildfly subsystem configuration. I had few email exchanges in keycloak email forum and was able to resolve the issue. Thanks.